# Meaning of id tag in repository tag in pom.xml

Tags: maven, artifactory, maven-plugin

Does repository identified by `id` have to exist at repository manager (Artifactory) or specifying correct `url` is enough?

```
<pluginRepositories>
<pluginRepository>
  <id>id</id>
  <name>name</name>
  <url>repo_mgr_url/repo_name</name>
</pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Maven build fails and from error i understood that plugin hasn't been found in repository identified by `id`.
I checked and found that indeed such repository doesn't exist in repository manager. I changed the `id` to some existing repository id and issue resolved. But didn't modify the `url` tag.

So, wonder what's the meaning of `id` if `url` hasn't changed? Searched in maven documentation to no avail.

Comment: Are you using the Maven Artifactory plugin?

Comment: no, don't use it, i try to build locally. build server probably, does have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `id` field can be anything. It has no meaning in the resolving the artifact.

You probably had some caching issue which caused a fail first and then it worked.